# Calculate the Determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
246 & 427 & 327 \\
1014 & 543 & 443 \\
-342 & 721 & 621 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

What's the trick?

Hints?

Of course I know calculate by definition...

Please don't do that by cheating.

Comment: What do you mean by trick? What is wrong with using the definition?

Comment: @Amzoti This is an exercise of the text, I wonder whether I should do that by definition. because they're not small numbers.

Comment: But the dimension is small; just use a calculator to multiply.

Comment: Subtract column 3 from column 2

Comment: One simplification would be to subtract the 3rd *column* (@ZevChonoles, did you mean column?) from the 2nd and pull out $100$ common giving you a smaller determinant.

Comment: I guess whoever created this problem wants you to subtract column 3 from column 2. That gives three 100's in the second column. Then subtract the first row from the other two, and the problem reduces to the computation of a 2 x 2 determinant.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, there is still one trick to go further, see my answer.

Comment: @ParthThakkar Thanks, there is still one trick to go further, see my answer.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, there is still one trick to go further, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First subtract the third column from the second as suggested by Gerry Myerson; this has no effect on the determinant.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
246 & 100 & 327\\
1014 & 100 & 443\\
-342 & 100 & 621
\end{array}\right]$$

Now divide the first column by $2$ and the second by $100$. These operations multiply the determinant by $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{100}$ respectively.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
123 & 1 & 327\\
507 & 1 & 443\\
-171 & 1 & 621
\end{array}\right]$$

Now add the first column to the third. This has no effect on the determinant.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
123 & 1 & 500\\
507 & 1 & 1000\\
-171 & 1 & 450
\end{array}\right]$$

Now divide the third column by $50$. This multiplies the determinant by $\frac{1}{50}$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
123 & 1 & 10\\
507 & 1 & 20\\
-171 & 1 & 9
\end{array}\right]$$

Now substract the third row from the first and second. These have no effect on the determinant.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
294 & 0 & 1\\
681 & 0 & 11\\
-171 & 1 & 9
\end{array}\right]$$

Now divide the first column by $3$. This multiplies the determinant by $\frac{1}{3}$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
98 & 0 & 1\\
227 & 0 & 11\\
-57 & 1 & 9
\end{array}\right]$$

If you expand along the second column, you should find that the computations are simple enough. To obtain the determinant of the original matrix, undo all of the effects of the column operations.

Comment: Thanks, after check the solution of the book. I found that there is still a trick after the collect of 100. I calculate 3 times to come across the simple answer.

Answer (score 5):

To simplify the calculation, you can start by subtracting column three from column 2. That will not change the value of the determinant, but will simplify its calculation. Then subtract the first row from the other two, and you can then, essentially, compute the value of the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix by expansion of the minor using the appropriate column.

In problems like this (particularly when looking to simplify the calculation of determinants of even larger matrices, we can use elementary row/column operations can  to simplify the calculation of the determinant, but recall if and how each operation impacts the value of the original determinant.

Comment: Thanks, there is still one trick to go further, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, everyone, after check the solution of the book(have a glance). I found that there is still a trick after the collect of 100.

I calculate 3 times to come across this simple answer.

\begin{align*}
d &= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 246 & 427 & 327 \\ 1014 & 543 & 443 \\ -342 & 721 & 621 \\\end{array}\right| \\
&= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 246 & 100 & 327 \\ 1014 & 100 & 443 \\ -342 & 100 & 621 \\\end{array}\right| \\
&= \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 246 & 100 & 327 \\ 768 & 0 & 116 \\ -588 & 0 & 294 \\\end{array}\right| \\
&=200 \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 123 & 1 & 327 \\ 384 & 0 & 116 \\ -294 & 0 & 294 \\\end{array}\right| \\
&=200 \left|\begin{array}{ccc} 123 & 1 & 450 \\ 384 & 0 & 500 \\ -294 & 0 & 0 \\\end{array}\right| \\
&=200 \times -294\times 500 \\
&=-29400000
\end{align*}

Comment: I neatened this answer up a bit, and also corrected the arithmetic.

Comment: There's still one mistake (although it doesn't affect the answer). I assume we get to the last matrix by adding column 1 to column 3, but if that's the case then the 327 should become 450.

Answer (score 1):

Sarrus rule:

$$\det(A) = \begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix} 
= a_{11}a_{22}a_{33} + a_{21}a_{32}a_{13} + a_{31}a_{12}a_{23}
-a_{11}a_{32}a_{23} - a_{21}a_{12}a_{33} - a_{31}a_{22}a_{13}$$

Look for example here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/determinants.pdf

Comment: I doubt that's what OP wants.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers ([see this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/161783)). Take screenshots or copy down the information yourself into the post, so that your answer will still make sense if external content is removed.

Comment: at G.M.: The answer was before the comments. at Z.C.: Okay, I wasn't aware of this. Thank you.

Comment: @ZevChonoles 
Thanks, there is still one trick to go further, see my answer.